# Spring REST Application with Microservices

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, consul, netflix-feign

I got this Spring Boot application that is now impossible to run standalone in development mode. It is configured to use Consul as service discovery. It works just fine when in a Docker container along with a Consul container (named as "consul-master"), however it will not start when I run from the IDE:

```
2018-06-03 21:57:32.844  INFO 88915 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@1018bde2: startup date [Sun Jun 03 21:57:32 BRT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-06-03 21:57:33.400  INFO 88915 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2018-06-03 21:57:33.611  INFO 88915 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.retry.annotation.RetryConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.retry.annotation.RetryConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7df8674f] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-06-03 21:57:33.629  INFO 88915 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a44ed227] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

.   ____          _            __ _ _
/\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
\\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
'  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
=========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
:: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.1.RELEASE)

2018-06-03 21:57:35.065 ERROR 88915 --- [           main] o.s.c.c.c.ConsulPropertySourceLocator    : Fail fast is set and there was an error reading configuration from consul.
2018-06-03 21:57:36.068 ERROR 88915 --- [           main] o.s.c.c.c.ConsulPropertySourceLocator    : Fail fast is set and there was an error reading configuration from consul.
2018-06-03 21:57:37.175 ERROR 88915 --- [           main] o.s.c.c.c.ConsulPropertySourceLocator    : Fail fast is set and there was an error reading configuration from consul.
2018-06-03 21:57:38.389 ERROR 88915 --- [           main] o.s.c.c.c.ConsulPropertySourceLocator    : Fail fast is set and there was an error reading configuration from consul.
2018-06-03 21:57:39.726 ERROR 88915 --- [           main] o.s.c.c.c.ConsulPropertySourceLocator    : Fail fast is set and there was an error reading configuration from consul.
2018-06-03 21:57:41.196 ERROR 88915 --- [           main] o.s.c.c.c.ConsulPropertySourceLocator    : Fail fast is set and there was an error reading configuration from consul.
2018-06-03 21:57:41.210 ERROR 88915 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

com.ecwid.consul.transport.TransportException: java.net.UnknownHostException: consul-master
    at com.ecwid.consul.transport.AbstractHttpTransport.executeRequest(AbstractHttpTransport.java:77) ~[consul-api-1.3.1.jar:na]
    at com.ecwid.consul.transport.AbstractHttpTransport.makeGetRequest(AbstractHttpTransport.java:34) ~[consul-api-1.3.1.jar:na]
    at com.ecwid.consul.v1.ConsulRawClient.makeGetRequest(ConsulRawClient.java:128) ~[consul-api-1.3.1.jar:na]
    at com.ecwid.consul.v1.kv.KeyValueConsulClient.getKVValues(KeyValueConsulClient.java:150) ~[consul-api-1.3.1.jar:na]
    at com.ecwid.consul.v1.ConsulClient.getKVValues(ConsulClient.java:534) ~[consul-api-1.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.consul.config.ConsulPropertySource.init(ConsulPropertySource.java:66) ~[spring-cloud-consul-config-2.0.0.RC1.jar:2.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.consul.config.ConsulPropertySourceLocator.create(ConsulPropertySourceLocator.java:166) ~[spring-cloud-consul-config-2.0.0.RC1.jar:2.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.consul.config.ConsulPropertySourceLocator.locate(ConsulPropertySourceLocator.java:132) ~[spring-cloud-consul-config-2.0.0.RC1.jar:2.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.consul.config.ConsulPropertySourceLocator$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$b35ebf8.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-consul-config-2.0.0.RC1.jar:2.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:747) ~[spring-aop-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor$1.doWithRetry(RetryOperationsInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-retry-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:287) ~[spring-retry-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:164) ~[spring-retry-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor.invoke(RetryOperationsInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-retry-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.retry.annotation.AnnotationAwareRetryOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AnnotationAwareRetryOperationsInterceptor.java:153) ~[spring-retry-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689) ~[spring-aop-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.consul.config.ConsulPropertySourceLocator$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bbd6bf74.locate(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-consul-config-2.0.0.RC1.jar:2.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.initialize(PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.java:94) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.0.0.RC1.jar:2.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:633) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:373) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:325) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at com.cimop.apigateway.App.main(App.java:26) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: consul-master
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1280) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:112) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:373) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:221) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:165) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:140) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
    at com.ecwid.consul.transport.AbstractHttpTransport.executeRequest(AbstractHttpTransport.java:61) ~[consul-api-1.3.1.jar:na]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
```

In a try to have it run on development mode ("dev" profile with `--spring.profiles.active=dev`), I used the following config (`bootstrap-dev.yml`):

```
spring:
  cloud:
    consul:
      enabled: false
```

The result is an exception that I don`t really understant how to fix:

```
2018-06-03 22:01:29.673  INFO 89049 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@55740540: startup date [Sun Jun 03 22:01:29 BRT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-06-03 22:01:30.248  INFO 89049 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2018-06-03 22:01:30.398  INFO 89049 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7dbf976e] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

.   ____          _            __ _ _
/\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
\\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
'  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
=========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
:: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.1.RELEASE)

2018-06-03 22:01:30.907  INFO 89049 --- [           main] com.cimop.apigateway.App                 : The following profiles are active: dev
2018-06-03 22:01:30.956  INFO 89049 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@5733f295: startup date [Sun Jun 03 22:01:30 BRT 2018]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@55740540
2018-06-03 22:01:32.700  INFO 89049 --- [           main] o.s.i.config.IntegrationRegistrar        : No bean named 'integrationHeaderChannelRegistry' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default DefaultHeaderChannelRegistry will be created.
2018-06-03 22:01:32.891  INFO 89049 --- [           main] a.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader : Skipping bean definition for [BeanMethod:name=configurableCompositeMessageConverter,declaringClass=org.springframework.cloud.stream.config.ContentTypeConfiguration]: a definition for bean 'integrationArgumentResolverMessageConverter' already exists. This top-level bean definition is considered as an override.
2018-06-03 22:01:33.151 ERROR 89049 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.ribbon.FeignRibbonClientAutoConfiguration.feignRequestOptions
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:64) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:179) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:141) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:117) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:328) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:233) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:694) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at com.cimop.apigateway.App.main(App.java:26) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.ribbon.DefaultFeignLoadBalancedConfiguration] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@4e25154f]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:659) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:556) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:541) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:599) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:724) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:665) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:633) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1489) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1012) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanTypeForNonAliasDefinition(BeanTypeRegistry.java:164) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanType(BeanTypeRegistry.java:153) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.updateTypesIfNecessary(BeanTypeRegistry.java:203) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.getNamesForType(BeanTypeRegistry.java:115) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:265) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:254) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:196) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:116) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/cloud/netflix/ribbon/SpringClientFactory
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:641) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.SpringClientFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    ... 38 common frames omitted

2018-06-03 22:01:33.153  INFO 89049 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@5733f295: startup date [Sun Jun 03 22:01:30 BRT 2018]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@55740540
2018-06-03 22:01:33.155  WARN 89049 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Unable to close ApplicationContext

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.ribbon.DefaultFeignLoadBalancedConfiguration] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@4e25154f]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:659) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:556) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:541) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:599) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:724) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:665) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:633) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1489) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:420) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:390) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:511) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:503) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1198) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:889) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:875) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:861) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:810) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at com.cimop.apigateway.App.main(App.java:26) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/cloud/netflix/ribbon/SpringClientFactory
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:641) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.SpringClientFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
```

In addition to that, I even tried to manually set a list of servers for FeignClient on `application.yml`:

```
integrationmicro:
  ribbon:
    listOfServers: 192.168.0.13:8001
```

Update:

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.companyname</groupId>
  <artifactId>apigateway</artifactId>
  <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>API Gateway</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- REST API -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
    </dependency>

  <!-- Security -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Database (MySQL) -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Microservices -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-all</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-consul-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RC1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-openfeign</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RC1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
          <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    consul:
      discovery:
        instanceId: ${spring.application.name}:${vcap.application.instance_id:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}}
        healthCheckPath: /health
      host: consul-master
      port: 8500
```

Comment: add your POM/dependencies

Comment: Updated with some more config files

Comment: While looking for solutions I noticed that *spring-boot-starter-parent* had a 2.0.2.RELEASE version and *spring-cloud-consul-dependencies* and *spring-cloud-openfeign* had a 2.0.0.RC2 version. After upgrade all it worked by just placing *NIWSServerListClassName* by the *listOfServers* and *spring.cloud.bus.enabled: false*

Answer (score 0):

When you run your service with docker and consul, it is registered to consul as it has its entry in docker-compose.yml file and registering part happens but we don't exactly see that. So you don't face any issues but when you run it through IDE you don't have it registered with consul therefore it throws `UnknownHostException`.

Basically you need to register your service to consul for its discovery.

I did it with following command,

`curl -X PUT -H 'application/json' -d '{"Node": "yourServiceName", "Address":"yourHost.com", "Service": {"Service": "yourServiceName", "Tags": ["proxy"],  "Port": 8080}}' http://yourHost/v1/catalog/register`

Note:

1.mention correct port and names.

2.run this above mentioned command from location where docker-compose.yml is present

Also you can refer [Consul Getting Started](https://www.consul.io/intro/getting-started/services.html)  and  [Consul Catalog API](https://www.consul.io/api/catalog.html) to get help for registering your locally running service to consul as above command is specific to my requirements by may not be suitable for yours.

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

The result of your dev profile usage:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.SpringClientFactory
```

just tells that you're missing that dependency in your app. Probably the app is configured in a way that those client libs are not loaded using dev profile - but then app doesn't provide any alternatives. You need to fix the app to either provide the library also on dev profile or, for example, mock that dependency out.